# How to validate min of a ion-input with Angular- Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, ngmodel

I need to show a message under the input when the user insert a number less than 0, i make the validation with ngModel and it doesn't work. The error that i have when i run the aplicattion is that 'campoNumerico' is not a object (TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.campoNumerico.errors'). I did the same with other input and it work, but doesn't work here. Help please. :'(

Plus: I installed ng2-validation to do this. Here is an example with input from html.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="model.field" name="field" #field="ngModel" [min]="10"/>
```

error message

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'campo_texto'">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input *ngIf= "campo.subtipo == 'number'" (ngModel)="campo.tipo" #campoNumerico="ngModel" name="{{campo.titulo.split(' ').join('_')}}" required="{{campo.esObligatorio}}" placeholder="{{campo.pista}}" type="{{campo.subtipo}}" [min]=0></ion-input>
      <ion-input *ngIf= "campo.subtipo != 'number'" (ngModel)="campo.tipo" name="{{campo.titulo.split(' ').join('_')}}" required="{{campo.esObligatorio}}" placeholder="{{campo.pista}}" type="{{campo.subtipo}}"></ion-input>         
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <p item-content *ngIf="campoNumerico.errors?.min">The number is not valid</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Since `campoNumerico` is only available conditionally, you need to access it accordingly. `<p item-content *ngIf="campoNumerico?.errors?.min">`

Comment: The error message is now fixed thank you, but i cannot show the message under the ion-input. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know. They should be showing up. Use the `| json` pipe to output some debugging info. Also, install the angular augery extension: https://augury.rangle.io/